# How to use emojionearea library in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, emojione

I try to using [emojionearea](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea) with jquery in webpack like

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import emojione from 'emojione'

$('.class').emojioneArea({... })
```

I tested Jquery working well But when using emojioneArea that has error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).emojioneArea is not a function
```

How to make that working, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document, it looks like you import the wrong package name. It's supposed to be `emojionearea` instead of `emojione`. I think you also need to expose `jquery` in the global for other plugins too as following:

```js
import $ from "jquery"
import 'emojionearea';

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

$('.class').emojioneArea({ ... })
```